# React how to change an individual button in a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I have a list that renders content from a base, each list item has a "Favorite" button to move the item to the start of the render. The problem is that I do not know how to change the icon of an individual element when I click on the "Favorite" (asterisk) button.

I tried to do it through LocalState, but because of this, when I click on a separate button "Add to favorites", everything changes at once

[Before pressing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2dpq.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5iN6.png)

Code

```
import { useState } from "react"

const WaysItem = (props) => {
    let [change, setChange] = useState(false)
    return props.directionsToRender.map((item, index) => (
        <li
            className={`ways-item`}
            key={index}
            onClick={() => {
                props.getCurrentDirections(index)
            }}
        >
            <div>
                <h5>{item.title}</h5>
            </div>
            <div className="ways-kilometrs">
                <div>{item.direction.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text}</div>
                <div>{item.direction.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text}</div>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => setChange((change) => !change)} key={index}>
                <i className={`${!change ? "far" : "fas"} fa-star`}></i>
            </button>
        </li>
    ))
}

export default WaysItem
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have array as a state . And add or remove index on button click.

```
import { useState } from "react"

const WaysItem = (props) => {
    let [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([])

    const onButtonClick = (index) => {
       // if index is already there in the selectedItems then remove it
       if(selectedItems.includes(index)){
         setSelectedItems(selectedItems.filter(item => item !== index))
       } else {
        setSelectedItems(prevSelectedItems => [...prevSelectedItems, index]);
       }
    }

    return props.directionsToRender.map((item, index) => {
      const showStar = selectedItems.includes(index);
      return (
        <li
            className={`ways-item`}
            key={index}
            onClick={() => {
                props.getCurrentDirections(index)
            }}
        >
            <div>
                <h5>{item.title}</h5>
            </div>
            <div className="ways-kilometrs">
                <div>{item.direction.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text}</div>
                <div>{item.direction.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text}</div>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => onButtonClick(index)} key={index}>
                <i className={`${showStar ? "far" : "fas"} fa-star`}></i>
            </button>
        </li>
    )})
}

export default WaysItem
```